# vba - Looping through the rows count and saving the value to variable

Tags: vba, excel

how can the pretty much the same codes could result in diferrent outputs?

This code:

```
Sub test()
  i = 1
    For d = 1 To 4
      i = i + 1
      Debug.Print i
    Next d
End Sub
```

prints 
 
 2 
 
 3 
 
 4 
 
 5

which is perfect, but this one

```
Sub test2()
  rcount = 34
    For d = 1 To 4
     rcount = Sheets("sheettest").Range(Range("A" & rcount + 4), Range("B" & rcount + 4).End(xlDown)).Offset(3, 0).Rows.Count
    Debug.Print rcount
    Next d
End sub
```

prints 
 
 203
 
 34 
 
 203 
 
 34

which is not what I expect

why the second value is 34 again?

Comment: Your 2nd code example shouldn't be running at all, the 4th line is incorrect.  What are you trying to accomplish?  What data is on the worksheet?

Comment: it must be incremented as .End(xlDown)  takes A:203 as a starting point.  I have many data blocks on the worksheet which have 3 rows as spaces among them I need to find how many rows are in each such data block (with the offset)

Comment: I'm sorry, it's tough to picture what you're trying to do without seeing the data, and knowing the end result.  Note that `.End(xlDown)` is selecting the rows, and so on the next loop, it's carrying on from that selection.  If that's not intentional, it would "reset" if you add something like `Range("A1").select` after the `FOR` Statement.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/etajL   - see the blocks are divided with 3 rows, the first block wth offset is 34 rows, the second is 203 and so on, I can not understand why there is a reset after first iteration and 34 again

Comment: I posted a code sample that should accomplish the same thing in a slightly different way.  It should print all the "section counts" in the Immediate Window.   Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what how you were trying to accomplish that and couldn't instantly put my finger on the problem, but I believe this will accomplish the same thing in a slightly different way.

```
Sub ListSectionCounts()

    Const colToCheck = 1 'check column A
    Dim sh As Worksheet, sectionRows As Long, sectionCount As Long, rw As Range

    Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use the currently selected sheet

    For Each rw In sh.UsedRange.Rows 'loop through all rows that have data
        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, colToCheck) <> "" Then
            'this row has data so count it
            sectionRows = sectionRows + 1
        Else
            'this row does not have data
            If sectionRows > 0 Then
                'if this is the 1st row without data then print the count and reset the counter
                sectionCount = sectionCount + 1
                Debug.Print "section #" & sectionCount & " row count: " & sectionRows
                sectionRows = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next rw

    'check if there's one more section to list
    If sectionRows > 0 Then
       sectionCount = sectionCount + 1
       Debug.Print "section #" & sectionCount & " row count: " & sectionRows
    End If

    Debug.Print "Finished (" & sectionCount & " sections)"
End Sub
```

(Try it as-is but then you may need to change the sheet from Activesheet and if you need it to check a column besides "A" then change `colToCheck`.)

---

**Edit:** Further to comments, this is the same code, same results, but squished and harder to figure out what's going on:

```
Sub secCnt()
For Each rw In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
  If Cells(rw.Row, 1) <> "" Then
    sRw = sRw + 1
  ElseIf sRw > 0 Then Debug.Print "rows:" & sRw: sRw = 0
  End If
Next rw
If sRw > 0 Then Debug.Print "rows:" & sRw
End Sub
```

---

## *"How I Troubleshoot..."*

I know you used my "alternate solution" but you were still wondering what was wrong with your code in the first place, as was I.  As I didn't write it, I wasn't sure how exactly you were trying to accomplish the goal until I split the problem into *much* smaller pieces, stepped through it, and put it back together in reverse.  I tend to keep a temp Notepad++ file when troubleshooting so I figured I'd share, and a couple others have asked me about my troubleshooting process.

Keep in mind I am self-taught (Google, baby!) so I likely break some coding standards.  Standardization in Coding exists for good reasons, and I am always learning, but at the end of the day I figure "whatever gets the job done" **is** the right way in the end.  By no means am I saying "my way is the right way" because there's plenty of "right" ways to tackle a problem.

(For now I'm pasting in my partially formatted notes, and I'll come back and reformat later!)

<sub>I didn't mean to hijack your thread but it was a great example I'd like to share with others who may be interested!</sub>

---

```
'Option Explicit

'How I trouble-shot the issue (explained the long way for future illustration purposes)
'Note I replaced `Sheets("sheettest")` with `ActiveSheet` for testing purposes; you may need to change that back

'I need to return the values:     11, 9, 7, 4    (based on my sample dataset)
'The problem code below returns:  11, 20, 11, 20  ...but why?
Sub test2_orig()
  rcount = 34
    For d = 1 To 4
     rcount = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("A" & rcount + 4), Range("B" & rcount + 4).End(xlDown)).Offset(3, 0).Rows.Count
    Debug.Print rcount
    Next d
End Sub
```

First I wanted to see EXACTLY what was happening each step of the way.  This can be accomplished by "[Watching](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/frice/2005/10/27/vba-beginners-corner-someone-to-watch-over-you/)" Variables (VBE Debug Menu) but I tend to go heavy on the `Debug.Print`'s instead.

```
Sub test2_1()
  rcount = 34
    For d = 1 To 4
     Debug.Print "d=" & d
     Debug.Print "rcount (before calculation)=", rcount
     rcount = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("A" & rcount + 4), Range("B" & rcount + 4).End(xlDown)).Offset(3, 0).Rows.Count
     Debug.Print "the calculation:", , "debug.print ActiveSheet.Range(Range(""A" & rcount + 4 & """), Range(""B" & rcount + 4 & """).End(xlDown)).Offset(3, 0).Rows.Count"
     Debug.Print "rcount (after calculation)= ", rcount
     Debug.Print "range (used in calculation)=", ActiveSheet.Range(Range("A" & rcount + 4), Range("B" & rcount + 4).End(xlDown)).Offset(3, 0).Address
     Debug.Print
   Next d
End Sub
```

**OUTPUT** (Sub test2_1):

```
d=1
rcount (before calculation)= 34
the calculation:             debug.print ActiveSheet.Range(Range("A15"), Range("B15").End(xlDown)).Offset(3, 0).Rows.Count
rcount (after calculation)=  11
range (used in calculation)= $A$18:$B$37

d=2
rcount (before calculation)= 11
the calculation:             debug.print ActiveSheet.Range(Range("A24"), Range("B24").End(xlDown)).Offset(3, 0).Rows.Count
rcount (after calculation)=  20
range (used in calculation)= $A$27:$B$37

d=3
rcount (before calculation)= 20
the calculation:             debug.print ActiveSheet.Range(Range("A15"), Range("B15").End(xlDown)).Offset(3, 0).Rows.Count
rcount (after calculation)=  11
range (used in calculation)= $A$18:$B$37

d=4
rcount (before calculation)= 11
the calculation:             debug.print ActiveSheet.Range(Range("A24"), Range("B24").End(xlDown)).Offset(3, 0).Rows.Count
rcount (after calculation)=  20
range (used in calculation)= $A$27:$B$37
```

Still a little unclear on your intended alogithm, it was best to break up the process into the smallest steps possible, to determine where the problem lies.  Don't `Loop` Yet, just try to get the first number right, with heavy commenting to talk myself through

```
Sub test2_2()
'get to first section (store row number in it's own variable)
Dim rowNum As Integer
rowNum = 34
'move down 4 rows to skip header
rowNum = rowNum + 4  ' = 38
'start range at A38 (and store it in a range object)
Dim rgStart As Range
Set rgStart = Range("A" & rowNum)
'end range at B.."End(xlDown)" (store it in a range object)
Dim rgEnd As Range
Set rgEnd = Range("B" & rowNum).End(xlDown)
'combine them into a single range object
Dim rg As Range
Set rg = Range(rgStart, rgEnd)
'count rows in the range (store separately)
Dim sectionCount As Integer
sectionCount = rg.Rows.Count
Debug.Print rgStart.Address & " to " & rgEnd.Address & " Row.Count = " & sectionCount
'this returned 11 (correct with my dataset)

'now we want to skip three rows and get the next range
'  (at this point I realized 1 of 2 issues with your original code, but I'll get back to that!)

'Rownum is still 38. RowNum + sectionCount + 3 will be the start of the headers of the next section:
rowNum = rowNum + sectionCount + 3
Debug.Print "next rowNum=" & rowNum

'theoretically we should be able to loop now, starting with the "skip 4 header rows" line...
'...instead of changing this sub, we can make a 2nd copy, saving this one for reference ("last working version") as we proceed
'...while tidying, we relocate all our variable declarations to the top of the new sub , and ensure Heavy Commenting for the sake of self & others
End Sub
```

.

```
'Our "tidied" version: (only cosmetic changes for now)
Sub test2_3()
Dim rowNum As Integer 'the current row number
Dim rgStart As Range 'start of the range for the current section
Dim rgEnd As Range 'end of the range for the current section
Dim rg As Range 'the entire range for the current section
Dim sectionRows As Integer 'count of the rows for the current section

rowNum = 34 'get to first section (begin loop AFTER here)

'BEGIN LOOP:
rowNum = rowNum + 4  'skip header (4 rows)
Set rgStart = Range("A" & rowNum) 'start range at A38
Set rgEnd = Range("B" & rowNum).End(xlDown) 'end range at column B, bottom row of this section
Set rg = Range(rgStart, rgEnd) 'combine into single range object
sectionRows = rg.Rows.Count 'count rows in the range

Debug.Print rgStart.Address & " to " & rgEnd.Address & " Row.Count = " & sectionRows 'for now stick with just debug.print'ing RowCount
'(a manual count tells me I'm expecting results: 11 -> 9 -> 7 -> 4 -> 2 using my sample dataset)
rowNum = rowNum + sectionRows + 3 'skip to top of next section
Debug.Print "next rowNum=" & rowNum

'************* Does it still work? Run it again; execution will `stop` ('break') on this line:
Stop '******** Drag the yellow marker up to the line after "BEGIN LOOP" and F5 to continue execution from there.

End Sub
```

Hooray, the numbers were correct!  Now to  automate the loop.  For..Next counters are not suited to this, since data tends to change.  Instead, at the end of each iteration of the loop, we'll check if there is data 4 rows below 'rgEnd'. (If so, 'Loop' again.)

```
Sub test2_4() 'Semi-Final Version:
    Dim rowNum As Integer 'the current row number
    Dim rgStart As Range 'start of the range for the current section
    Dim rgEnd As Range 'end of the range for the current section
    Dim rg As Range 'the entire range for the current section
    Dim sectionRows As Integer 'count of the rows for the current section

    rowNum = 34 'get to first section (begin loop AFTER here)

    Do 'BEGIN LOOP:
        rowNum = rowNum + 4  'skip header (4 rows)
        Set rgStart = Range("A" & rowNum) 'start range at A38
        Set rgEnd = Range("B" & rowNum).End(xlDown) 'end range at column B, bottom row of this section
        Set rg = Range(rgStart, rgEnd) 'combine into single range object
        sectionRows = rg.Rows.Count 'count rows in the range

        Debug.Print rgStart.Address & " to " & rgEnd.Address & " Row.Count = " & sectionRows 'for now stick with just debug.print'ing RowCount
        '(a manual count tells me I'm expecting results: 11 -> 9 -> 7 -> 4 -> 2 using my sample dataset)
        rowNum = rowNum + sectionRows + 3 'skip to top of next section
    Loop Until rgEnd.Offset(4, 0) = "" 'loop until there ISN'T data 4 rows below rgEnd
    Debug.Print "Done!"
End Sub
```

Now we have the sub functioning like we intended.  There's no reason it can't stay like this, but many dev's (myself included) can be particular about shrinking code.  It goes much smoother in reverse like this; just remember to maintain commenting as much as possible, and don't over-minimize!

```
'Final Version:
Sub test2_5_Final()
    Dim rowNum As Integer, sectionRows As Integer, sectionNum As Integer 'counters: current row, rows in section, section number
    Dim rgStart As Range, rgEnd As Range, rg As Range 'start/end/complete ranges for "current section"

    rowNum = 34 'first section's top row
    Do
        rowNum = rowNum + 4  'skip header
        Set rgStart = Range("A" & rowNum) 'section top-left
        Set rgEnd = Range("B" & rowNum).End(xlDown) 'section bottom-right
        Set rg = Range(rgStart, rgEnd) 'whole section
        sectionRows = rg.Rows.Count 'count rows in section
        sectionNum = sectionNum + 1 'increase count of sections
        Debug.Print "Section #" & sectionNum & " = " & sectionRows & " rows" 'store the values somewhere else if need be
        rowNum = rowNum + sectionRows + 3 'skip to top of next section
    Loop Until rgEnd.Offset(4, 0) = "" 'loop until there's no data 4 rows down
    Debug.Print "Done!"
End Sub
```

Finally, through troubleshooting & rewriting I realized the issues with your original code:

1. Variable `rcount` was being used for *both* current row # and for count of rows in current section, thus alternating each run
2. Right-bracket on the wrong site of the `Offset` referred to the entire range instead of just the bottom of it.

   - [Range.Offset Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-offset-property-excel)
   - [Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel)

*Solution*: Corrected bracket and Added a Variable.  The above code will likely be more reliable, but just for the heck of it:

```
Sub test2_orig_fixed()
    Dim d As Integer, rcount As Integer, secCount As Integer
    rcount = 34
    For d = 1 To 4
        secCount = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("A" & rcount + 4), Range("B" & rcount + 4).End(xlDown).Offset(3, 0)).Rows.Count
        Debug.Print secCount - 3
        rcount = rcount + secCount + 4
    Next d
End Sub
```

Getting into the habit of methodically troubleshooting small issues like this example will be nothing but beneficial when tackling bigger issues in the future.

Everyone's brain tackles logic problems in different ways.  This is how *I* handle it, but there are countless other methods (and there are even University-level courses on Troubleshooting Theory.)  Who needs puzzles when we have code!

Comment: seems like ok but it only finds 3 sections instead of 4, and I wanted to understand why my code is not workign, what is wrong with its logic? thanks

Comment: output of your code                                                                           
section #1 row count: 34
section #2 row count: 203
section #3 row count: 35
Finished (3 sections)

Comment: Honestly the 1st problem with troubleshooting your code is it's too compressed. It's easier to understand and troubleshoot if you break it up into more lines and do one baby step at a time. First get it find the beginning of a section, and store that location in a variable. Then find the end of it, and store that in a different variable. Then create a third range variable that is the beginning and end together. Then create an integer which is the count of the rows. It may seem trivial but it's a huge help in troubleshooting. Once everything's working, squish it down to 3 lines all you like! :)

Comment: so you're saying there are actually 4 sections? oh, it's probably not listing the very last count. After `next rw`, put `debug.print sectionrows`.  Is that the count of the missing block? (ie., this method only loops the "used" rows but if the last row is "used" my code won't think it's done.  Minor change would fix that.)

Comment: yes it is. when putting debug.print sectionrows it shows the count of the last section.

Comment: i modified the code in my answer,  There are many ways to accomplish the same task, this was just one I slapped together that did the trick.

Comment: so you are saying that if I break my code down to many strings I will understand why it is not working?

Comment: I'm saying that, for me, with my code, I am guaranteed to find a bug if I break my code down to the smallest sections possible, and step through line by line (with lots of breakpoint or `stop` statements).  It can be time consuming at times but saves frustration (and solves my problem) in the end.  It's also tough to look at someone else's uncommented code, especially if they are using methods I not very familiar with.  But  like anything in VBA, there are dozens of ways to accomplish any single task, and in my opinion, is the one that _works_ (although others would disagree!)

Comment: ...my posted code could be squished down to a couple lines and so the same thing but would be much harder to follow, or to change later, etc.  I like to know what every single line is doing.  (did you try my edited code?)

Comment: I got it, just was interested why my code is not working as it has such straightforward logic..